# How to integrate plugin "cordova-plugin-connectsdk" in Ionic 3 app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, live-connect-sdk

I'm new to Ionic and want to to know how to use connectsdk to play the videos in TV from Ionic 3 app.

Actually I want to use this plugin "cordova-plugin-connectsdk" in ionic 3 but I don't know how to integrate this plugin in ionic 3

I tried to install the plugin from here(http://www.svlconnectsdk.com/docs/1-6-0/cordova/setup-instructions/) but it is not installing and giving error 
i.e. Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-connectsdk': Error: Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'

other than this plugin I'm able to install other native plugins of ionic

Please help if anyone know about integration of "cordova-plugin-connectsdk" plugin ionic 3.

Comment: Kindly show your current efforts and precisely tell us where the problem is. Why are you not able to follow the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826547.aspx

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: (Chatty messages, txtspk, case errors and general pleading tends to be edited out here, and are not worth restoring - please be willing to accept edits from experienced users, since I/they have an understanding of the desire for quality here).

Comment: Actually I want to use this plugin "cordova-plugin-connectsdk" in ionic 3 but I don't know how to integrate this plugin in ionic 3

Answer (score 1):

Use it Ionic Video Player, see [Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/video-player/)

you can also see video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4S1yVBUPpk)

Using this plugin you can play video

if you wont Streaming videos use it [Cordova Streaming Media plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-streaming-media)